# Iterating on elements of Scheme-vector causes contract violation

Tags: string, vector, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm trying to write a function that checks if the given input holds any characters other than digits . However , I get `contract violation` in DrRacket under Scheme .

Here's the code :

A method that separating a string into characters :

```
(define (breaking str) (list->vector (string->list str)))
```

Creating a vector for the number :

```
(define myNumber (breaking "123498765"))
```

Here I check the given number :

```
(define (vectorFunc myVector)
(define i 0)                      
(do ()                             
  ((= i (vector-length myVector))) ; run until the end of the vector
  (cond ((< (vector-ref myVector i) #\0) 'incorrect)
        ((> (vector-ref myVector i) #\9)  'also-incorrect))
  (set! i (+ i 1))    ; inc "i+ by 1
); end of do
)
```

And the output of `(vectorFunc myNumber)` is :

```
. . >: contract violation
  expected: real?
  given: #\1
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
   #\0
>
```

What's wrong with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to determine if a value is a character between `#\0` and `#\9`, better use the [`char-numeric?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._char-numeric%7E3f%29%29) predicate:

```
(char-numeric? a-char)
```

From the documentation:

> Returns #t if char has the Unicode “Numeric” property.

In the case of your code, it looks like this:

```
(cond ((not (char-numeric? (vector-ref myVector i)))
       'incorrect)
      (else ...))
```

I agree with @LudwigMeier's comment - your code doesn't look Scheme-like. You're trying to use Scheme as if it were a C-like language, and it looks a bit weird. In Scheme things are done ... different.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to `char-numeric?`! :)

Comment: @Óscar López: If I run `(define myNumber (breaking "dsdsadsa"))` then I get `char-numeric?: contract violation
  expected: char?
  given: 1`

Comment: @Óscar López: Okay you win :) your suggestion works great ! +1 & chosen !

Comment: @ron really? it works for me, `char-numeric?` simply returns `#f`. are you sure you are passing chars and only chars to the predicate? the error states that you passed the number `1`

Answer (score 2):

As Racket tells you correctly, you are comparing apples and oranges in your `cond`-branch, i.e. chars with reals; `string->list` creates a list of *chars*. You could write your own predicate to overcome this problem and map it over a vector (which would be a more functional solution – your code does not look very scheme-like ;) )

```
(define (breaking str)
  (list->vector (string->list str)))

(define my-number
  (breaking "1234987650"))

(define (represents-char-number? char)
  (if (member char '(#\0 #\1 #\2 #\3 #\4 #\5 #\6 #\7 #\8 #\9))
      #t
      #f))

(define (vector-func vec)
  (vector-map represents-char-number? vec))

(vector-func my-number)
===> #(#t #t #t #t #t #t #t #t #t #t)
```

`vector-map` is standartized within R6RS. Please consider also some [style-rules](http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt) for languages of the lisp-family.

Comment: Don't forget the `#\0` char ;)